# Intensity vs wavelength graph of blackbody radiation

Tags: electromagnetism

In the intensity vs wavelength graph of blackbody radiation, how some photons still radiate energy value other than the peak value wavelength? 
On atomic level how some atoms are able to radiate photons of more or less energy(with less or more wavelength)?

Comment: Related ?: [What are the various physical mechanisms for energy transfer to the photon during blackbody emission?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59213/what-are-the-various-physical-mechanisms-for-energy-transfer-to-the-photon-durin), [Black body radiation at atomic level](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/283250/black-body-radiation-at-atomic-level)

Comment: @KeithMcClary thank you so much it helped me a lot. I got what I was looking for.